# Unable to send Response from Rest method

Tags: java, rest, jersey

Here is the rest ws POST method code:

```
        @POST 
        @Path("/json/saveuser")
        @Consumes("application/json")
        public ResponseBuilder saveUserJSON(User user) {
            if (save(user)) {
                return Response.status(HttpStatus.SC_OK);
            }
            return Response.status(HttpStatus.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
        }
```

**User is saved properly in DB.**

But the line `Response.status(HttpStatus.SC_OK);` and `Response.status(HttpStatus.SC_BAD_REQUEST);`, is throwing below error:

```
Mar 06, 2015 1:38:49 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse traceException
SEVERE: Mapped exception to response: 500 (Internal Server Error)
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.ResponseBuilderImpl, and Java type class javax.ws.rs.core.Response$ResponseBuilder, and MIME media type application/octet-stream was not found
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:278)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1326)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1239)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1229)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:420)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:497)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:684)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.ResponseBuilderImpl, and Java type class javax.ws.rs.core.Response$ResponseBuilder, and MIME media type application/octet-stream was not found
    ... 28 more
```

Did googling. And according to the posts in SO and other sites, added the jars as listed below (Some additional jars are also added for other dependency):

```
antlr-2.7.7.jar
com.sun.jersey.jersey-core-1.4.0.jar
com.sun.jersey.jersey-server-1.4.0.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
gcm.server.jar
genson-0.98.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.5.Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
http-core-4.1.jar
jackson-all-1.9.0.jar
jackson-annotations-2.2.2.jar
jackson-core-2.2.2.jar
jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar
javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar
jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar
jboss-logging-3.1.4.GA.jar
jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1.jar
jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
jersey-bundle-1.8.jar
jersey-container-servlet-core-2.16.jar
jersey-core-1.15.jar
jersey-json.jar
json_simple-1.1.jar
lucene-core-4.10.4.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.1.31.jar
slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
xml-apis-1.3.03.jar
```

**Not sure what am I missing? Any suggestion?**

Comment: You need to return `Response` not `ResponseBuilder` in the signature. And call `build()` at the end of your `Response` building

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to return a Response instead of a ResponseBuilder:

```
@POST 
@Path("/json/saveuser")
@Consumes("application/json")
public Response saveUserJSON(User user) {
    if (save(user)) {
        return Response.status(HttpStatus.SC_OK).build();
    }
        return Response.status(HttpStatus.SC_BAD_REQUEST).build();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your stacktrace obviously points, that Jersey doesn't know, how to response with ResponseBuilder. 
Return Response instead: change resource method signature and return result of build method, called upon builder.